# debug evento desconocido previene copiar con CTRL+C

Tags: javascript, jquery

Un evento desconocido (no se cual ya busque en mis script javascript)
esta previniendo que copie contenido del código html mostrado en la web.

alguna manera de hacer un debbug que me indique que funcion o que linea de código esta previniendo que al presionar CTRL+C Copie al porta papeles del S.O.

no se si es alguna funcion jquery o alguna otro pluggin.

**update:**
he quitado de uno en uno los script que tiene el sistema hasta llegar al que detiene o previene el CTRL+C

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 13: //Previene el uso del Enter
            return false;
            break;
        case 112: //F1
            return window.ayuda();
            break;
        case 117: //tecla asignada al scaner de barra
            alert('Sin desarrollar el sistema lector de barras');
            return false;
            break;
        case 116://F5 Control del refrescar.
            var reload = true;
            if (reload) {
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Abre la consola del desarrollador y sigue el código desde el inicio de carga de la página.

Comment: ya lo intente y no encontre nada ...

Comment: es decir que ya utilizaste el debbugger statement en tu codigo cierto?

Comment: es correcto amigo ya lo he usado pero no me funciona ya que desconozco cual es el evento especifico o funcion o archivo que esta provocando o previene el copiado de CTRL+C

Comment: Por que haces `return false`?

Comment: @MikelFerreiro es lo sugerido aqui para que haga el stop propagation despues de que se intenta usar una tecla o keyCode. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1404596/10771500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pueda que no tenga nada que ver con el js, puede ser el html o el css. Verifica si tienes alguna de estas:

**CSS**

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

**HTML**

```
<body oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false">
```

Comment: si al parecer era eso un compañero agrego a un div un css similar como el que indicas...